# Single column layout for category and search results

Tags: layout, page-layouts, luma-theme, page

I have Magento 2 installed and am using the Luma theme. I've disabled the wishlist and compare but I still have a left sidebar on the category and search result pages. Which files do I have to edit/override in order to have a single column layout for both pages.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Category Layout**

You don't need to disable **wishlist and compare**.

You just have to override `catalog_category_view.xml` and change `layout="1column"` write below code.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"> ... </page>
```

for the category layout you can also change from admin panel **Products -> Categories -> "cat1" -> Custom Design**.

[image: change category layout]

**Search Layout**

same as for search override `catalogsearch_advanced_result.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"> ... </page>
```

Comment: The first part of your solution doesn't work. Stays at 2-columns-left